# track twitter hashtags using twit through socket.io

Tags: javascript, json, twitter, socket.io

I would like to create an if statement in my emit function that says: if the hashtag is x, then send through this ID, if the hashtag is y, then send through that ID. I'm guessing that its best to do this server side. How would I do this? (I think I need to filter the JSON result)

Here is my server side code:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var Twit = require('twit');
var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key:         'JBJUBMi6uBz1j4587RHoWVWX9' // Your Consumer Key
  , consumer_secret:      'ChwkS3eXX0obPAGPaw5thpRt8bMr4nbNa7fK3Vc4M8Bieeegr0' // Your Consumer Secret
  , access_token:         '150020683-nztFnojPcUyxUVXllWXFJ9p99JAaTA6MFE6tr5Wx' // Your Access Token
  , access_token_secret:  'jzQMrFnAFjyqMEC7aIDI5hymElWf329Y1dysj0vOAiEGu' // Your Access Token Secret
});


app.use(express.static(__dirname +'/public'));

//routes



app.route('/cool')
    .get(function(req,res){

        res.sendFile(__dirname+'/public/html/404.html');

    });

    var server = app.listen(3000, function(){

console.log(" the server is running on port 3000");

    })

    var socketio = require("socket.io");
    var io = socketio.listen(server);
    var nbOpenSockets = 0;
    var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: 'liberal, conservative'})


    io.on('connection',function(socket){



console.log('Client connected !');
    if (nbOpenSockets <= 0) {
        nbOpenSockets = 0;
        console.log('First active client. Start streaming from Twitter');
        stream.start();
    }

    nbOpenSockets++;

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('Client disconnected !');
        nbOpenSockets--;

        if (nbOpenSockets <= 0) {
            nbOpenSockets = 0;
            console.log("No active client. Stop streaming from Twitter");
            stream.stop();
        }
    });


        socket.on('changeBackground', function(newColour) {

            console.log(newColour);

            socket.emit('setBackground', newColour);

            socket.broadcast.emit('setBackground', newColour);

        }); 

        stream.on('tweet', function(tweet) {

socket.emit('info', { tweet: tweet });


});

        socket.emit('initialize', "initialized");

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

By using IndexOf and assigning an ID to that hashtag, I was able to pass the id through to the client:

```
stream.on('tweet', function(tweet) {

    // console.log(tweet);

    if(tweet.text.indexOf('#war') > -1) {
        console.log("war")

     socket.emit('info', {tweet:"war"});   

    }
```